# How do I change a list I read from a file so that it changes when the program is running but resets when the program ends?

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to make this program that reads from a file and puts the contents of the file into a list, which has worked out so far.  I'm able to do menu options 1, 2, and 6.

But option 3 (where it sorts the list alphabetically), doesn't do anything to change the list.

This is after I've tried copying the sorted list into the "global" team_list. Note, I am NOT trying to change the file, I only wish to change the list within the different features in the while loop so that if you pick option 3 to sort them, it sorts the list alphabetically. But if you were to choose option 2 after choosing option 3, it would display all the names alphabetically.

```
The .txt file:
Boston Americans
New York Giants
Chicago White Sox
Chicago Cubs
Chicago Cubs
Pittsburgh Pirates
Philadelphia Athletics
Philadelphia Athletics
Boston Red Sox
Philadelphia Athletics
Boston Braves
Boston Red Sox
Boston Red Sox
Chicago White Sox
Boston Red Sox
Cincinnati Reds
Cleveland Indians
New York Giants
New York Giants
New York Yankees
Washington Senators
Pittsburgh Pirates
St. Louis Cardinals
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
Philadelphia Athletics
Philadelphia Athletics
St. Louis Cardinals
New York Yankees
New York Giants
St. Louis Cardinals
Detroit Tigers
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
Cincinnati Reds
New York Yankees
St. Louis Cardinals
New York Yankees
St. Louis Cardinals
Detroit Tigers
St. Louis Cardinals
New York Yankees
Cleveland Indians
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
New York Giants
Brooklyn Dodgers
New York Yankees
Milwaukee Braves
New York Yankees
Los Angeles Dodgers
Pittsburgh Pirates
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
Los Angeles Dodgers
St. Louis Cardinals
Los Angeles Dodgers
Baltimore Orioles
St. Louis Cardinals
Detroit Tigers
New York Mets
Baltimore Orioles
Pittsburgh Pirates
Oakland Athletics
Oakland Athletics
Oakland Athletics
Cincinnati Reds
Cincinnati Reds
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
Pittsburgh Pirates
Philadelphia Phillies
Los Angeles Dodgers
St. Louis Cardinals
Baltimore Orioles
Detroit Tigers
Kansas City Royals
New York Mets
Minnesota Twins
Los Angeles Dodgers
Oakland Athletics
Cincinnati Reds
Minnesota Twins
Toronto Blue Jays
Toronto Blue Jays
Atlanta Braves
New York Yankees
Florida Marlins
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
New York Yankees
Arizona Diamondbacks
Anaheim Angels
Florida Marlins
Boston Red Sox
Chicago White Sox
St. Louis Cardinals
Boston Red Sox
Philadelphia Phillies

START_DATE = 1903
END_DATE = 2009
FILE = 'WorldSeriesWinners.txt'


def main():
    team_list = file_to_list(FILE)
    quit_program = False

    while not quit_program:
        print('-' * 50)

        print('1. Search a team')
        print('2. Display team names')
        print('3. Sort team names in alphabetical order')
        print('4. Sort team names in reverse-alphabetical order')
        print('5. Remove a team name')
        print('6. Quit')

        user_response = int(input('Choose an option (1-6): '))
        while user_response < 1 or user_response > 6:
            user_response = int(input('Please choose a valid option (1-6): '))

        if user_response == 1:
            wins = 0
            chosen_team = input('Enter a team name: ')
            if chosen_team in team_list:
                for index in range(len(team_list)):
                    if team_list[index] == chosen_team:
                        wins = wins + 1
                print(f'The {chosen_team} won the world series {wins} times between {START_DATE} and {END_DATE}')
            else:
                print(f'The {chosen_team} are not on the list.')

        elif user_response == 2:
            display(team_list)

        elif user_response == 3:
            unique_team_names = set(team_list)
            new_team_list = list(unique_team_names)
            new_team_list.sort()

        elif user_response == 6:
            quit_program = True

    print('Goodbye')


def file_to_list(file_name):
    try:
        team_file = open(file_name, 'r')
        team_list = []

        team = team_file.readline()

        while team != '':
            team = team.rstrip('\n')
            team_list.append(team)
            team = team_file.readline()

        team_file.close()

        return team_list
    except IOError:
        print('File not found')


def display(team_list):
    unique_team_names = set(team_list)
    new_team_list = list(unique_team_names)
    for index in range(len(new_team_list)):
        print(new_team_list[index])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide a sample content of `WorldSeriesWinners.txt`

Comment: what's your problem? do you want reset a list or your option 3 is not working as you want?

Comment: @UmairLakhani Option 3 isn't working as intended. I tried copying the sorted list into the main "team_list" list but it doesn't copy it into it. Meaning option 3 does not work.

Comment: I tried your code, it's working fine. just print(new_team_list) in user_response == 3